# accumulation point of a subset and accumulation point of an indexed family of subsets of space $X$.

Tags: general-topology

Let $\xi=\{V_n:n\in\omega\}$ be a sequence of open subsets of space $X$. For every $n\in\omega$, choose $x_n\in V_n$.

> If $p\in X$ is an accumulation point of $\{x_n:n\in\omega\}$, then is is true that $p$ is an accumulation point of family $\xi$, that is, $\xi$ is not locally finite at point $p$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: Let $U$ be an open neighborhood of $p$. let $M_U=\{n\in\omega:x_n\in U\}$.

- Is $M_U$ finite, or infinite?
- If $n\in M_U$, what can you say about $U\cap V_n$?

**Added:** If you don’t assume that $X$ is $T_1$, $\xi$ need not be locally finite at $p$. Let $X=\omega$, and let $\tau=\{U\subseteq\omega:0\notin U\text{ or }\{0,1\}\subseteq U\}$; $\tau$ is a $T_0$ topology on $X$. For $n\in\omega\setminus\{0\}$ let $U_n=\{n\}\in\tau$, and let $\xi=\{U_n:n\in\omega\setminus\{0\}\}$. Clearly we must pick $x_n=n$ for each $n\in\omega\setminus\{0\}$, and $p=0$ is an accumulation point of $\{x_n:n\in\omega\setminus\{0\}\}=\omega\setminus\{0\}$: every open nbhd of $p$ contains $1=x_1$. But $\{0,1\}$ is an open nbhd of $p$ that meets only one member of $\xi$.

Comment: If $X$ is a metric space or $T_1$ then $M_U$ is infinite, and therefore $p$ is an accumulation point of family $\xi$. but how about an arbitary space $X$?

Comment: @NBhr: Exactly what definition of *accumulation point* are you using?

Comment: Every neighbourhood $N$ of $p$ contains a point of $\{x_n:n\in\omega\}$ different from $p$.

Comment: @NBhr: Okay; then the answer is *not necesarily* if you don’t assume some reasonable minimum amount of separation. I’ll add an example to the answer.

Comment: Thank you for this favor. Is there exists another definition of accumulation point?

Comment: @NBhr: That’s the usual definition, and I was pretty sure that it’s what you had in mind, but you might have been thinking of the sequence $\langle x_n:n\in\omega\rangle$ instead of the set $\{x_n:n\in\omega\}$ and using *accumulation point* to mean *cluster point*. In that case a single point of the **set** $\{x_n:n\in\omega\}$ might be infinitely many terms of the **sequence**, which would complicate matters. And I have occasionally seen a definition that requires that every nbhd of $p$ contain infinitely many points of the set.